# How in a multipart node impose the height of each part

Tags: tikz-pgf, size, multipart-node

In the example below I need all frames to have the same height.
How to force the height of each part of the node?

[image]

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% % !TeX spellcheck = fr 

\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{ positioning,calc,shapes.multipart }
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{SIunitx}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every two node part/.style={red,minimum size=3em}]

\tikzset{cadre/.style={draw, text width=10em,align=center,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,minimum height=12em}}
\node[ cadre](mot)
{Moteur triphasé
\nodepart{two}
$C_m$, $\omega_m$\\
Inertie de l'arbre moteur:\\ $J_m=\SI{1.3e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$};
\node[right=2em of mot,cadre](redu){Réducteur
\nodepart{two}
rapport de réduction $r=\num{58.6}$\\
Rendement $\eta_r=\num{0.74}$\\
Inertie du réducteur ramené sur l'arbre de sortie\\
$J_{red}=\SI{1.8e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$};


\node[right=2em of redu,cadre](tamb){
Tambour
\nodepart{two}
$\omega_T$\\
Inertie du tambour\\
$J_{T}=\SI{1.37}{\kilogram\metre^2}$
};


\node[below=5em of tamb,cadre](cablerolu){
Câble enroulé
\nodepart{two}
Inertie câble enroulé  sur le tambour\\
$J_{C}$
};


\node[left=2em of cablerolu,cadre](cablederolu){
Câble déroulé
\nodepart{two}
Longueur câble déroulé: $\ell_C$\\
Longueur totale:$L_{max}=\SI{200}{\metre}$\\
masse linéique $\rho_L=\SI{0.368}{\kilogram\per\metre}$
};


\node[left=2em of cablederolu,cadre](sonde){
Sonde
\nodepart{two}
Masse: $M_s =\SI{ 5,6}{\kilogram}$\\
Vitesse $v_s$
};

\draw [-latex] (mot) --(redu);
\draw[-latex]  (redu)-- (tamb);
\draw[-latex]  (tamb.east)--++(2em,0)|-(cablerolu);
\draw[-latex] (cablerolu) -- (cablederolu);
\draw [-latex]   (cablederolu) -- (sonde);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, this is not possible. you should use two nodes or labels to mine node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if the following solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning}
\usepackage{SIunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 4mm and 8mm,
every label/.style = {label distance=0pt, draw,
                      text width=10em, text depth=0.3ex,
                      align=center, outer sep=0pt},
      cadre/.style = {draw, minimum height=12em, text width=10em,
                      outer sep=0pt, align=center, text=red,
                      label=above:#1}
                       ]
\node[cadre=Moteur triphasé] (mot)  {$C_m$, $\omega_m$\\
                                     Inertie de l'arbre moteur:\\ $J_m=\SI{1.3e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$
                                     };
\node[cadre=Réducteur,
      right=of mot]     (redu)      {rapport de réduction $r=\num{58.6}$\\
                                     Rendement $\eta_r=\num{0.74}$\\
                                     Inertie du réducteur ramené sur l'arbre de sortie\\
                                     $J_{red}=\SI{1.8e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$
                                     };
\node[cadre=Tambour,
      right=of redu]        (tamb)      {$\omega_T$\\
                                         Inertie du tambour\\
                                         $J_{T}=\SI{1.37}{\kilogram\metre^2}$
                                        };
\node[cadre=Câble enroulé,
      below=of tamb]    (cablerolu)     {Inertie câble enroulé  sur le tambour\\
                                         $J_{C}$
                                        };
\node[cadre=Câble déroulé,
      left=of cablerolu](cablederolu)   {$\ell_C$\\
                                         Longueur totale:$L_{max}=\SI{200}{\metre}$\\
                                         masse linéique $\rho_L=\SI{0.368}{\kilogram\per\metre}$
                                        };
\node[cadre=Sonde,
      left=of cablederolu]  (sonde)     {Masse: $M_s =\SI{ 5,6}{\kilogram}$\\
                                         Vitesse $v_s$
                                        };
\draw[-latex]   (mot)   edge (redu)
                (redu)  edge (tamb)
                (cablerolu) edge (cablederolu)
                (cablederolu) edge  (sonde)
                (tamb.east)-- ++(2em,0) |-(cablerolu);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: merci.
I did not think about using the labels. But it's still a pity not to have the opportunity to impose the size of the different parts, At first, I had a node in 3 part, it would not have been possible to go through the labels .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `fit`, with which case the texts are top-aligned.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes.multipart,fit}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every two node part/.style={red,minimum size=3em}]

\tikzset{cadre/.style={text width=10em,align=center,rectangle split, rectangle
split parts=2,minimum height=12em},my fit/.style={draw,inner sep=0pt}}
\node[ cadre](mot)
{Moteur triphasé
\nodepart{two}
$C_m$, $\omega_m$\\
Inertie de l'arbre moteur:\\ $J_m=\SI{1.3e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$};
\path ($(mot.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (motaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(mot) (motaux)](fmot){};
%
\node[right=2em of mot.north east,anchor=north west,cadre](redu){Réducteur
\nodepart{two}
rapport de réduction $r=\num{58.6}$\\
Rendement $\eta_r=\num{0.74}$\\
Inertie du réducteur ramené sur l'arbre de sortie\\
$J_{red}=\SI{1.8e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$};
\path ($(redu.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (reduaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(redu) (reduaux)](fredu){};
%
\node[right=2em of redu.north east,anchor=north west,cadre](tamb){
Tambour
\nodepart{two}
$\omega_T$\\
Inertie du tambour\\
$J_{T}=\SI{1.37}{\kilogram\metre^2}$
};
\path ($(tamb.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (tambaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(tamb) (tambaux)](ftamb){};
%
\node[below=2em of ftamb,cadre](cablerolu){
Câble enroulé
\nodepart{two}
Inertie câble enroulé  sur le tambour\\
$J_{C}$
};
\path ($(cablerolu.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (cableroluaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(cablerolu) (cableroluaux)](fcablerolu){};
%
\node[left=2em of cablerolu.north west,anchor=north east,cadre](cablederolu){
Câble déroulé
\nodepart{two}
Longueur câble déroulé: $\ell_C$\\
Longueur totale:$L_{max}=\SI{200}{\metre}$\\
masse linéique $\rho_L=\SI{0.368}{\kilogram\per\metre}$
};
\path ($(cablederolu.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (cablederoluaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(cablederolu) (cablederoluaux)](fcablederolu){};
%
\node[left=2em of cablederolu.north west,anchor=north east,cadre](sonde){
Sonde
\nodepart{two}
Masse: $M_s =\SI{ 5,6}{\kilogram}$\\
Vitesse $v_s$
};
\path ($(sonde.north)+(0,-4.2cm)$) coordinate (sondeaux);
\node[my fit,fit=(sonde) (sondeaux)](fsonde){};
%
\draw [-latex] (fmot) --(fredu);
\draw[-latex]  (fredu)-- (ftamb);
\draw[-latex]  (ftamb.east)--++(2em,0)|-(fcablerolu);
\draw[-latex] (fcablerolu) -- (fcablederolu);
\draw [-latex]   (fcablederolu) -- (fsonde);
%
\foreach \X in {mot,redu,tamb,cablerolu,cablederolu,sonde}
{\draw (\X.text split west) --  (\X.text split east);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `TikZ` you could use a `tcbraster` with `raster equal height` option and `remember as` boxes which will allow to draw arrows between boxes.

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% % !TeX spellcheck = fr 

\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{SIunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=3,
    raster column skip=1cm,
    raster left skip=0pt,
    raster right skip=8mm,
    raster row skip=1cm,
    raster equal height,
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    center title,
    colback=white,
    colupper=red,
    halign=center,
    remember as=\thetcbrasternum
    ]
    \tcbitem[title=Moteur triphasé] $C_m$, $\omega_m$\\ Inertie de l'arbre moteur:\\ $J_m=\SI{1.3e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$

    \tcbitem[title=Réducteur] rapport de réduction $r=\num{58.6}$\\
Rendement $\eta_r=\num{0.74}$\\
Inertie du réducteur ramené sur l'arbre de sortie\\
$J_{red}=\SI{1.8e-3}{\kilogram\metre^2}$

    \tcbitem[title=Tambour] $\omega_T$\\
Inertie du tambour\\$J_{T}=\SI{1.37}{\kilogram\metre^2}$

    \tcbitem[title=Sonde] Masse: $M_s =\SI{ 5,6}{\kilogram}$\\
Vitesse $v_s$

    \tcbitem[title=Câble déroulé] Longueur câble déroulé: $\ell_C$\\
Longueur totale:$L_{max}=\SI{200}{\metre}$\\
masse linéique $\rho_L=\SI{0.368}{\kilogram\per\metre}$

    \tcbitem[title=Câble enroulé] Inertie câble enroulé  sur le tambour\\
$J_{C}$
\end{tcbitemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ->]
\draw (1)--(2); 
\draw (2)--(3); 
\draw (3.east)--++(0:5mm)|-(6); 
\draw (6)--(5); 
\draw (5)--(4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]